# SQL Server merge replication error "The schema script 'xxx.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber"

Tags: sql-server-2005, merge-replication

I recently made some changes to a working publication under Merge replication which seem to have broken synchronization for the subscriber.

The error message I'm getting is:

```
The schema script 'ftdb_arcmessagefac64b65_76.sch' could not be propagated
to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001
The process could not read file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\xxx\20120701000581\xxxx.sch' due to OS error 3. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL0
```

I've looked in the unc directory, and there's no directory `20120701000581`, but there's a directory `20120706110881` from when the snapshot of the publication was updated.

I've tried reinitializing the subscription and recreating the snapshot, but the process still fails expecting the `20120701000581`.

I haven't tried deleting and recreating the subscription yet, as I would rather get to the bottom of the issue before trying this. Can someone explain what may be happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Also note I tried deleting and recreating the subscriber along with the above, but this made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, it appeared that I was able to make some changes to the article properties in the subscription and once the snapshot was rebuilt the subscription resynchronization ran successfully.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a missing old replication folder in \\servername]\ReplData\unc\.Your answer is not very useful for anyone to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

this happen because subscriber cant locate snaps so you can share snaps folder in your network using UNC

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151151.aspx

Answer (score 0):

View snapshot agent status-> Monitor-> Right Click on Error Subscription and choose Reinitialize.
Good luck